# I need a safe reliable way to increase the number of files in OOo's Recent Documents list

Tags: openoffice

The [wiki page at apache](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/FAQ/General/I_need_to_see_more_than_the_default_4_items_on_the_list_of_recently_opened_files._How_do_I_achieve_this%3F) has links to extensions and macros that do not seem to exist any more, and I cannot follow the written instructions for hand editing because there is no `<node oor:name="History">` in my registrymodifications.xcu file

Answer (score 0):

#### There is no  in my registrymodifications.xcu file

According to [Can I access a list of recent documents longer than 10 entries?](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/941/can-i-access-a-list-of-recent-documents-longer-than-10-entries/) you need to **add** this entry to `registrymodifications.xcu`:

> You can edit your configuration settings and add the PickListSize
>   entry in main.xcd (or in your local configuration, then you'd have to
>   add it to registrymodifications.xcu in the user profile):
>
> ```
> <prop oor:name="PickListSize" oor:type="xs:int">
>  <value>20</value>
> </prop>
> ```

Try adding:

```
<node oor:name="History">
```

Followed by the above lines.

> has links to extensions and macros that do not seem to exist

The link [History Manager Extension](http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/en/project/histmngr) works for me.

Comment: that's strange, when I follow your link, I get a download button that works.  Previously, it failed. :-?

Comment: In general, I'm a little nervous about upvoting your answer because it appears from the comments on the page you've linked to, that it is assumed that the reader knows how to add the necessary elements to the xml file without breaking it.  Same assumption on the page I originally quoted, which is why I said I couldn't follow the directions due to the missing <node>.  One day I may dust off my copy of Oxygen and start tinkering with the files, but that might be a ways down the road....

Comment: So you are not going to vote for an answer that worked better than what you had in terms of download because other readers may not have knowledge ... I will though...